# Reordering Columns in a Gridview Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview I'm trying to reorder the columns for, but I'm getting an object not found error.
The code works when I don't include the code under "//code to move columns", but when I include that code, I get an object not found error that "s += txtAD.Text.Trim();" object reference is not set to an instance. It's weird because no matter which columns I switch, it always throws the error that it can't find column 1.

Any ideas?

My HTML:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridviewtxSLds" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="gridclassscrolledtx" CellPadding="0" ForeColor="#333333" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Metric">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("item") %>'
                    ID="txtctrltype" class="modalpopup2" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AD">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AD") %>'
                    ID="txtAD" onfocus="blur()" class="txttime" AutoPostBack="false" ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BD">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BD") %>'
                    ID="txtBD" onfocus="blur()" class="txttime" AutoPostBack="false" ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CD">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CD") %>'
                    ID="txtCD" onfocus="blur()" class="txttime" AutoPostBack="false" ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

code in codebehind to fill gridview

```
using (var cmdtx2 = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd, conn))
{
    DataTable dv = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter db = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdtx2);

    //code to move columns
    var columnMove = gridviewtxSLds.Columns[3];
    gridviewtxSLds.Columns.RemoveAt(3);
    gridviewtxSLds.Columns.Insert(2, columnMove);

    db.Fill(dv);
    gridviewtxSLds.DataSource = dv;
    gridviewtxSLds.DataBind();
}
```

Update code, which throws the error:

```
protected void Bulk_Insert(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var timeinitid = hfptstate.Value;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < gridviewtxSLds.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        #region textbox declarations
        TextBox txtitem = gridviewtxSLds.Rows[i].FindControl("txtctrltype") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtAD = gridviewtxSLds.Rows[i].FindControl("txtAD") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtBD = gridviewtxSLds.Rows[i].FindControl("txtBD") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtCD = gridviewtxSLds.Rows[i].FindControl("txtCD") as TextBox;
        #endregion textbox declarations

        #region command string
        string s = "update 1874tx set AD";
        s += "='";
        //following line throws the error
        s += txtAD.Text.Trim();
        s += "', ";
        s += "BD";
        s += "='";
        s += txtBD.Text.Trim();
        s += "', ";
        s += "CD";
        s += "='";
        s += txtCD.Text.Trim();
        s += "' where item";
        s += "='";
        s += txtitem.Text.Trim();
        s += "';";
        #endregion
        sb.Append(s.ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Edit: And before anyone comments on concatenation of SQL queries, I know, and for this specific use it doesn't matter.

Comment: Your given code works, please post the code which creates issue.

Comment: Hm. Any idea in general what kind of code may be causing the error? The whole solution is about 50,000 lines. 
The stack trace literally just lists the button click, postback, then the error in the update function.

Comment: Is it possible that the column switching code is emptying the gridview somehow? That's the only reason I can think why the update is giving the object reference error... but I don't know why switching columns would do that.

Comment: Yes its the issue.

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?